# MS SQL Server - Left join with group by in both left and right table

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in MS SQL Server.

Table A contains a list of Customer IDs, and the products they have purchased.

Products are bundled together to form a package.

Table B contains the groups of products, and the packages that they form.

Example:

Table A:

```
CustID     Product
-------------------
10001      Mobo_1
10001      GPU_1
10002      Mobo_1
10002      GPU_2
```

Table B:

```
Product    Package
-------------------
Mobo_1     Pack_A
GPU_1      Pack_A
Mobo_1     Pack_B
GPU_2      Pack_B
```

I would like to map the Package column from Table B to Table A, taking into consideration the specific combination of products that a specific customer purchased,

i.e. Mobo_1 + GPU_1 should map to Pack_A, and Mobo_1 + GPU_2 should map to Pack_B.

Resulting output:

```
CustID     Product     Package
-------------------------------
10001      Mobo_1      Pack_A
10001      GPU_1       Pack_A
10002      Mobo_1      Pack_B
10002      GPU_2       Pack_B
```

I have tried searching for `LEFT JOIN` + `GROUP BY` + `WHERE` conditions, but could not seem to find any similar questions or solutions.

Comment: What is the logic to find `10002 Mobo_1 Pack_B` ?

Comment: Re "I have tried searching for ..." - do you know that there's always possibility to write down reqired logic and then the query itself, without any searching for existent code? Sure you can always ask, if some bit of your code behaves in unexpected way :)

Comment: @GuidoG I'm rather new to SQL, so I'm not sure if it is possible, but the intention is to group CustID together in Table A, such that CustID: 10002 has a group of two products - Mobo_1 + GPU_2. And group Packages in Table B together, such that Pack_B has a group of two products - Mobo_1 + GPU_2. Then these two groups would act as a match for CustID: 10002 to Pack_B.

Comment: How do you know which one to assign though? There is no ordering on the table, and there is no indication why one row should go with another. Why do you get `10001      Mobo_1      Pack_A` and `10001      Mobo_1      Pack_B` rather than just two of each (as with a normal join) or two of only one (with a `TOP 1` or `ROW_NUMBER` style query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can be done, but it takes some effort

```
select a.CustID,
       a.Product,
       t3.Package
from   TableA a
  left join ( select t.CustID,
                     t2.Package
              from   ( select  a.CustID,
                               ( select top 1 string_agg(a.Product, '+')
                                 from   TableA a2
                                 where  a2.CustID = a.CustID
                               ) as Products
                       from    TableA a
                       group by a.CustID
                     ) t   
                left join ( select b.Package,
                                   ( select top 1 string_agg(b.Product, '+')
                                     from   TableB b2
                                     where  b2.Package = b.Package
                                   ) as Products
                            from   TableB b
                            group by b.Package
                          ) t2 on t.Products = t2.Products
            ) t3 on a.CustID = t3.CustID
```

the result is

```
CustID  Product Package
10001   Mobo_1  Pack_A
10001   GPU_1   Pack_A
10002   Mobo_1  Pack_B
10002   GPU_2   Pack_B
```

You can try it yourself [at this DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7b31b00d59f5622d8a1af28694c73a6a)

**EDIT**

The trick I used is to combine the products into one varchar ('Mobo_1+GPI_1' and 'Mobo_1+GPI_2') for both tables, and then you can use those varchar's to join.
It will be more clear when you look at the last queries in the DBFiddle